# Variable 'isVericated' captured by a closure before being initialized - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, closures, face-id

I am trying to return a boolean variable named `isVerificated` from a function named `identityVerification`, so I can use it in the `tableView` function. The function `identityVerification` starts ID verification through Face ID or Touch ID and the returned variable `isVerificated`, which tells if the verification was successful or not.

**In other words:**
My goal is when you click on a cell in TableView, it should firstly start identity verification using Face ID or Touch ID. Then after successful identity verification, a new ViewController will be opened. If the identity authentication fails, the app will display an AlertController with a message: "Authentication failed" and the new ViewController will not be opened.

**The problem:**
When I run the app there appears two errors:

1. (!) Variable 'isVericated' captured by a closure before being initialized
2. (!) Variable 'isVericated' used before being initialized

**Here is the code:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let IDisVarificated = identityVerification()    //here the "identityVerification" function is started
        if IDisVarificated == true {
            if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detail") as? PasswordTVcontroller {
                navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
        } else {return}
    }
    
    
    func identityVerification() -> Bool {
        var isVerificated: Bool
        let context = LAContext()
        var error: NSError?

        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {   //HERE IS ERROR NUMBER 1
            let reason = "Identify yourself!"

            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {
                [weak self] success, authenticationError in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if success {
                        isVerificated = true    //verification was successfull
                    } else {
                        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication failed", message: "You could not be verified; please try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                        self?.present(ac, animated: true)
                        isVerificated = false     //verification failed
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Biometry unavailable", message: "Your device is not configured for biometric authentication.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            self.present(ac, animated: true)
            isVerificated = false      //verification failed
        }
        
        return isVerificated      //returning a variable with boolean value that tells if verification was successfull or not, HERE IS ERROR NUMBER 2
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think that you might solve the problem just by initializing the variable on declaration `var isVerificated = false`

Comment: Declaring your `isVerificated` as a `var` with an initial value of `false` would silence the compiler warning, but it would not fix the fact that you won't have the result of your async call when you return from your `identityVerification()` function. See my answer for the correct solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of question comes up all the time with people who are new to async functions.

You can't write a function that returns a result from The `LAContext` function `evaluatePolicy(_:localizedReason:reply:)`. Period.

That function is asynchronous. That means it does not return a result. It returns immediately, and then does the work you've asked it to do in the background. Once the work is done, it invokes the `reply` closure.

Your code attempts to set a local variable, `isVerificated`, inside the closure. That won't work. By the time the closure is run, your function has already returned.

You need to rewrite your function identityVerification to take a closure rather than returning a function. The refactored function might look like this:

```
func identityVerification(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
        let context = LAContext()
        var error: NSError?

        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {   //HERE IS ERROR NUMBER 1
            let reason = "Identify yourself!"

            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {
                [weak self] success, authenticationError in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if success {
                        completion(true)
                    } else {
                        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication failed", message: "You could not be verified; please try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                        self?.present(ac, animated: true)
                        completion(false)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Biometry unavailable", message: "Your device is not configured for biometric authentication.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            self.present(ac, animated: true)
            completion(false)
        }
}
```